# Touchables don't work in modal on android (RN)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-modal

I'm using the following package (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) for creating modals in my RN app.

Inside the modal, I have some buttons: TouchableOpacity and TouchableWithoutFeedback, both imported from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

Problem: the buttons work on iOS, but not on Android. The buttons **outside** the modal do work on both platforms, but on Android not in the modal.

Changing the import from `react-native-gesture-handler` to importing the touchables from `react-native` self did not fix the issue.

Has somebody faced the same issue before?